# Swift. How to add a UIView on top of a GMSPanoramaView

Tags: swift, google-maps, uiview, subview

I have a simple `GMSPanoramaView` and I want to add a UIView on top of it, I've tryed whith addSubview and changing the layers zposition but I't dosen't show up.
Any idea's on how I can do it?

The way I implemented the GMSPanoramaView:

```
let panoView = GMSPanoramaView(frame: CGRectZero)
self.view = panoView

panoView.moveNearCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Approach 1:

```
var yourView = UIView()
self.view.bringSubviewToFront(yourView)
```

Approach 2:

```
var gmsView = GMSPanoramaView()
self.view.addSubview(gmsView)
var anotherView = UIView()
self.view.insertSubview(anotherView, aboveSubview: gmsView)
```

This should work!!

Comment: Niether og those works, I've just updated my question so you can see how i'm implementing the GMSPanoramaView, because i'm not adding it as a subview